# It is giving me an error as prototype is undefined?

Tags: c

It is giving me an error as key_type_t is undefined. How to define this type of enum?

I have an enumerated type that looks like this:

```
typedef enum {
        MODE ,
        Up ,
        DOWN ,
        LEFT ,
        RIGHT,
        SET 
  } key_type_t;
```

I have a function declared which looks like this:

```
void key_type_to_str(key_type_t key_type)
             {...}
```

I have its prototype and it looks like this:

```
void key_type_to_str(key_type_t key_type);
```

Comment: We'll need a [mcve]. Something we can plugin into a compiler and get the same error as you.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat  the way I defined it is correct?

Comment: Your structure declaration is okay. Make sure you declared the prototype in right place.

Comment: @Md.FaisalHabib yeah I have declared the prototype in the right place in the same way as others but also it says identifier key_type_t is undefined.

Comment: @gretal I've posted an answer. Please check how you've been using the structure in your code.

Comment: As with your previous question, the error is in the part you do not show us. The snippets are correct, you are just not putting them in correct place. But without seeing that part, we can only guess. And again, you refuse to update your question to show requested missing parts. That is not really tha attitute to attract people who could help you because such incomplete questions are useless for visitors dealing with similar problems.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your existing code seems okay.

What you've to check is how you've been using it.

Here's a sample code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
typedef enum
{
    MODE,
    Up,
    DOWN,
    LEFT,
    RIGHT,
    SET
} key_type_t;

void key_type_to_str(key_type_t key_type);

int main()
{
    key_type_t temp;
    key_type_to_str(temp);
}

void key_type_to_str(key_type_t key_type)
{

    printf("function key_type_to_str has been called\n");
}
```

Output:

```
function key_type_to_str has been called
```

Comment: Habib, thanks a lot, much appreciated.

Comment: Glad to help. Happy coding